# macro to re-arrange data

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write a macro to re-arrange the Cells in the rows and columns of Stock tables for the output I desire. Luckily the Stock Tables are generally the same each and every time (Different names and values), and the desired outcome is the same format..

Here is some example Data.

```
      A
```

1 Name
2 description
3 description
4 description
5 description
6 ID#: 56284
7 Quantity in stock: 34
8 Zoom In and Configure

```
      B
```

1 Name
2 description
3 description
4 description
5 description
6 ID#: 56284
7 Quantity in stock: 50
8 Zoom In and Configure

And I would like the Output to go into something like this(If possible to sheet2 starting on Cell B2):

```
B    C    E
```

B Being Row 1
C being Row 2 3 4 and 5 Combined
E being JUST Row 7 Stock Value I.E 50

On a single spreadsheet there would be 4 columns, and 8 rows I would have to re-arrange.. Making 32 total.

It would be great to automated this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify my understanding. For each column you want the following data format:

```
    A                                              A
1   Name                                       1   Name
2   Desc1                                      2   Desc1; Desc2; Desc3; Desc4
3   Desc2                      On sheet 2      3   50
4   Desc3                   --------------->
5   Desc4
6   Id#: 56284
7   Quantity in Stock: 50
8   Zoom in and configure
```

If this is the case you can use the following code. It assumes your data is in A1 to D8 in Sheet 1.

```
Sub FormatData()
    Dim col As Integer

    For col = 1 To 4
        With Worksheets(2)
           .Cells(1, col) = Cells(1, col) //Get name
           .Cells(2, col) = Cells(2, col) & "; " & Cells(3, col) & "; " & Cells(4, col) & "; " & Cells(5, col) //Concatenate descriptions into single string
           .Cells(3, col) = Cells(7, col) //Get quantity in stock
        End With
    Next col
End Sub
```